# Why is there a property `type` on a NGXS Action

Tags: ngxs

I'm reading about [NGXS](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/actions) and which, for example, looks like this:

```
export class NewState {
    static readonly type = '[State] New';
    constructor(public payload: MyState) { }
}
```

In my store I can listen for that action

```
@Action(New)
newState(ctx: StateContext<MyState>, { payload }: { payload: MyState }) {
    ctx.setState(payload);
}
```

So, although I specified a static type as `[State] New` I don't see it anywhere coming back in my code.

My first thought was, because it is an identifier, it is needed if you have multiple action, like this

```
@Action(New)
@Action(Add)
newState(ctx: StateContext<MyState>, action: MyState | AddState) {
    if (action.constructor.type === New.type) {
        ctx.setState(payload);
    } else {
        // do something else
    } 
}
```

But then again, you can do it without `type` of course like this `action.constructor === New` and probably even better to just use a separate function fo each one of them :)

So, my question is: When should I use `type`?

Comment: Unless it's changed in recent versions (I don't think so) the type is used internally by NGXS to invoke the appropriate state methods for a particular action - so each actions needs a unique string as its type.

Comment: In your example of multiple actions, unless both actions result in the same change to the state then you'd want to handle them separately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that would explain it, but still a bit weird that there is nothing in the docs about this. Also, I think you could, for the purpose of identifying, use the class itself.

Comment: I answered your question below, but on another note to handle multiple actions in the same action handler, use an array: `@Action([Action1, Action2])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need type. That's how NGXS works. It doesn't check based on an instance.
[From the docs](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/actions#group-your-actions):

> Each action contains a `type` field which is their unique identifier.

Comment: And who is using that unique identifier? If it is something internal only I would think that it is possible to use the class instead and you don't have to bother the developer with any of that, right

Comment: I hear ya... but I think this is more of a JS state management community type convention/standard. NGRX/Redux/etc... all use some sort of type mechanism. But it is useful though, still. As the developer you can use `getActionTypeFromInstance()` to handle specific cases. See the docs when creating a meta reducer: https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/meta-reducer

Comment: Ok, if it is a standard way of doing things regarding state management it makes sense I guess. But event with that `getActionTypeFromInstance` example you could as well do: `action instanceof Logout` :)